# UICollectionView insertItems(at:) not completing before other code

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Thanks already for your time! I've been working with collection views, and am totally stumped on a very small part of my code that is not behaving how I'd expect. Here are the two lines (which I think are the only ones that are relevant):

```swift
diceCollectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
diceCollectionView.contentInset.top = 
    max((diceCollectionView.frame.height - 
    diceCollectionView.contentSize.height) / 2, 0)
```

The application that I'm building is a dice rolling calculator, and the GUI is essentially a collection view where the user presses a button to add a "die" to the view. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the items in the collection view be vertically centered by adding that top content inset after an item is inserted. What is happening, however, is it seems that the content inset is being calculated *before* the item has been inserted, so the content size used in that calculation is the content size before the item is introduced.

Here is a screenshot when a single item is added (see how the top of the cell is at the center of the collection view):

[Single item added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYj3I.png)

After adding a second one, the content inset is calculated correctly:

[Second item added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBU0x.png)

Am I doing this the wrong way here? I've thought that the answer might lie in closures or in using a Dispatch Queue, but I haven't had any luck with those. I am extremely stumped! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `contentInsets` after the `insertItems` completion handler is called.

```
diceCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    self.diceCollectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
}) { (completed) -> Void in
     self.diceCollectionView.contentInset.top =
            max((self.diceCollectionView.frame.height -  self.diceCollectionView.contentSize.height) / 2, 0)
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! This makes a ton of sense, and just about gets the job done. The only slight issue is that now the inset is added as soon as the default animation is completed, so the cell will begin to "fade in" above where it should be, and then snap to the desired position once that animation is finished. Thank you so much because you've answered my initial question! Do you have any recommendations of where to go from here?

Comment: @GoodTimeHaver I didn't understand your question. Do you want it to move to the desired position smoothly after the animation is finished ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how you could make the animation begin in the desired position. Currently I'm thinking you would just set the inset before insertItems(at:) is called, using something other than the Collection View's content size.

Comment: I don't want to pile on too much more "questioning" with this one topic, but I'm also tempted to use the Collection View's insetForSectionAtIndex method. This would work great if I were just displaying a static amount of information, but since the user is adding things at run time, wouldn't that throw things off? My understanding is that insetForSectionAtIndex isn't called when there are items inserted into the view.

Comment: You are correct `insetForSectionAtIndex` will not be called when items are inserted. I am actually not sure about how to begin the animation at the correct position. Will have to check that once